# can 'best' go without "the" here?

Tags: articles, zero-article

> Best companies have best mangment.

It's not a slogan or a headline - just a sentence from a text. Is it gramatically coorrect, or you still need 'the' before 'best' here? Somehow it sounds better without "the" to me since the meaning is genereal (best companies in general and best managment in general).

Comment: Without the articles, it sounds like ["*headlinese"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese). Personally, I would put a *the* in front of each *best*. It might be acceptable without—particularly as a slogan—but if it's a sentence within regular text, it would be unusual.

Comment: Jason Bassford - It is a sentence within regular text. I've changed the discription...

Comment: You need "the" before "Best" and before "best" - actually I can't think of any example where you could drop "the" before "best", except as mentioned above, in a headline, where you can drop words like "the" sometimes.

Comment: Note that you spelled *management* wrong in two different ways.

Comment: Unless, unlikely as it may be, the word "Best" here is a family name. Or a brand name or the name of a management school or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

To use it as a sentence, and have it correct, you must say:

> **The** best companies have **the** best management.

Reason: in both cases, you have an adjective in the superlative. When using the superlative, the definite article cannot be avoided or replaced with something else.